# Probability using statistics

Tags: statistics

Scenario: A company that makes cartons finds the probability of producing a carton with a puncture is 0.05. The probability that a carton has a smashed corner is 0.08. The probability that a carton has a puncture and a smashed corner is 0.004.

Question: If a quality inspector randomly selects a carton, find the probability that the carton has a puncture or has a smashed corner.

Comment: Tried the formula but I'm not coming up with an answer with a decimal

Comment: What formula? What sort of answer are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ and $S$ respectively be the events "the carton has a puncture" and "the carton has a smashed corner":

$$P(P \cup S) = P(P) + P(S) - P(P \cap S)$$

Thus, what you are looking for is 0.126

The property invoked is true for all [non mutually exclusive events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability#Not_mutually_exclusive_events).